# Is there any way to convert Spring data interface projections with google Gson?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Im developing a system that relies heavily on data projections as the entities are quite big but rarely do I need the whole entity, hence Im using projections (interface projections).
Now my project uses gson and its HttpConverter but it throws me an exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: com.manager.projections.StaffProjection. Forgot to register a type adapter?; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: com.manager.projections.StaffProjection. Forgot to register a type adapter?
```

Is there any way to tackle this issue without needing to define JsonSerializers for all my projections? I have quite a few...

Comment: I think the problem is that the interface projections are returned as proxy objects, which are not serializable. That might be the problem.
On the other hand, are you returning the repository layer's objects directly to the Controller's response. Did you try to use DTOs to decouple the layers?
Then you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: I had dtos for the whole entities. When using projectios i didnt create them. I use model mapper to map between dao <-> dto. Do you think that would work?

Comment: If in the Controller you return exactly the projection object retrieved by the repository, then I have no doubt It won't work.
Think you don't have a concrete implementation of those interfaces, then Spring creates dynamic proxies for them, and they are not serializable.
Try creating a simplified DTO and return it instead of the projection and maybe you'll get surprised. Let me know how it results and I'll post an answer for that. :)

Comment: I tried to, but model mapper doesn't seem to be able to convert the dao -> dto because its a spring proxy. Im aware i can make the constructors but since its a lot of projections i was trying to save myself the work and the sheer code spam it would take